# How to find from which cell text is contained in given cell

Tags: excel, search, match, vlookup

So I have a formula that shows if a cell contains text from a list:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("List of companies in Worksheet A",A1)))>0`

It works correct, but I need to further expand this formula.

I have a two data worksheet:

W1 is a list of companies and that show preferred companies for given product in given country,

W2 is a list of documents that show which company has been use in which country for which product.

I need formula that shows if for given document the company is preferred for given country and product.

Above formula solved the issue of company as it checks if company mentioned in W2 appears in W1, now I would need to add two more conditions, to check the country and product.

Current formula is this:

`=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("List of companies in Worksheet A",A1)))>0,"Preferred", "Non Preferred")`

How do I reverse the formula so it will show me in WHICH cell the found value in W1 is so I can use simple VLOOKUP and = formula and and the conditions, like:

`=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("List of companies in Worksheet A",A1)))>0,B1=Vlookup(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("List of companies in Worksheet A",A1))>0,Table in W1,1,"Preferred", "Non Preferred")`

I am really stuck, please help.

**An example of worksheet A**

| Company Name | Company Code | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abd | 12355 | Germany |
| aaa | 23322 | Austria |
| asc | 432 | France |
| asc | 123 | USA |
| asce | 1234 | Poland |

**An Example of worksheet B**

| Company Name | Country |
| --- | --- |
| abd - 111 | Germany |
| aaa - 234 | Austria |
| asc - 432 | France |
| asc - 123 | UK |
| asce - 1234 | Romania |

If I use:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("List of companies in Worksheet A",A1)))>0`

It will highlight 3 bottom rows, however I need to apply second condition so it will highlight ONLY 3rd row, the one with France.

Comment: Coulld you post a data example and the expected output?

Comment: Likely index() with match() would work.

Comment: Hello @SolarMike
I have added an example of data with expected outcome.
Could you help me writing the second part of the formula, I actually tired using Index and Match formulas but it did not work.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Kris_Toor Looking at your examples, you just want the Country in Worksheet B to be fetched from Worksheet A according to Company Name? In that case, shouldn't `asc -123` be `USA` instead of `UK`? Same for `asce - 1234` (it should be `Poland` instead of `Romania`)

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns
 Thank you for your message.
Actually no, as you can see I am talking here about highlighting, that is this formula is for Conditional Formatting (I am sorry I might not have been clear about it). So what I need a formula, that 1. will check if a company is on list on Worksheet A, AND THEN 2. if it is there if the country matches.
The formula is not to fetch any information from one spreadsheet to another but to compare them.

Comment: So you would highlight worksheet B, value France because is the only one that matches company name and code?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes, exactly, I would like it to highlight third row, because it maches the code, the, country AND the name all 3 of them.
The issue with my task is that I have list of companies, and for many name and company code are the same for example: Company WarmIce with code 1234 works in  Nordic region: in Denmark, Sweden and Finland, but on my B list I would have for WarmIce 1234 working in Iceland - the formula that I presented above will still highlight this row but it is incorrect, it happens because it filters ONLY number and name, doesn't consider country.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting is pretty hard because CF rules don't allow to use references to other worksheets besides current one neither array formulas. But you may use a helper column to get the output you need and then hightlight based on that output:

Worksheet A

[image]

Worksheet B

[image]

Notice `France` is the only highlighted value because is the only country that fits pattern `Company Name - Company&CodeCountry`

Formula in column C (array formula, so you must introduce it pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>:

```
={ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2&B2;'Worksheet A'!$A$2:$A$6&" - "&'Worksheet A'!$B$2:$B$6&'Worksheet A'!$C$2:$C$6;0))}
```

CR rule to highlight applied to column B is based on this formula:

```
=C2=TRUE()
```

**UPDATE:** If you really really need to skip the helper column, you may benefit from function INDIRECT:

> [INDIRECT
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

But if your dataset is big, **I don't recommend this solution** because it may really overcharge your file because INDIRECT is a volatile function:

> [INDIRECT – Excel’s Most Evil
> Function](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/)

Besides, if your dataset is fixed (I mean it goes always in the same Address like A2:C6 or A2:A1000, whatever but always the same) you may use it, but it it changes all the time, it will slow down your file.

Anyways, you can make a CF rule based on this formula:

[image]

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2&B2;INDIRECT("'Worksheet A'!$A$2:$A$6")&" - "&INDIRECT("'Worksheet A'!$B$2:$B$6")&INDIRECT("'Worksheet A'!$C$2:$C$6");0))
```